# Incorrect syntax in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

While executing below dynamic SQL, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near ','

Code:

```
declare @site varchar(40) = ''

begin
    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL SELECT TP.F_PRODUCT AS ID FROM PDF_MSDS_NEW TP WHERE TP.F_AUTHORIZED IN(1,3) AND TP.F_PRODUCT <>'' AND (TP.F_TEXT_CODE LIKE @SITE), @SITE NVARCHAR(10),SITE0001
end
```

Now i changed my above query.It is not showing any error message now but output is not coming.

```
CREATE TABLE PDF_MSDS_NEW(F_PRODUCT VARCHAR(50),F_AUTHORIZED INT,F_TEXT_CODE VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO PDF_MSDS_NEW VALUES('F0001',1,'SITE0001')

DECLARE
@SITE VARCHAR(100),
@statement nvarchar(max)
BEGIN
set @SITE='SITE0001'
set @statement ='SELECT TP.F_PRODUCT AS ID FROM PDF_MSDS_NEW TP WHERE TP.F_AUTHORIZED IN(1,3)AND TP.F_PRODUCT <>'''' AND (TP.F_TEXT_CODE LIKE @SITE)'
PRINT @statement
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @statement ,N'@SITE NVARCHAR',@SITE
END
```

Comment: the last two commas seem misplaced..?

Comment: [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has two or more parameters. The first two parameters should be of type `NVARCHAR(X)`. Review the link for some examples.

Comment: Now i changed my query.I posted my new query.Now error message is coming but output is not coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I changed your dynamic SQL to accept the parameter into the Set statement.

```
CREATE TABLE PDF_MSDS_NEW(F_PRODUCT VARCHAR(50),F_AUTHORIZED INT,F_TEXT_CODE VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO PDF_MSDS_NEW VALUES('F0001',1,'SITE0001')

DECLARE
@SITE VARCHAR(100),
@statement nvarchar(max)
BEGIN
set @SITE='SITE0001'
set @statement ='SELECT TP.F_PRODUCT AS ID FROM PDF_MSDS_NEW TP WHERE TP.F_AUTHORIZED IN(1,3)AND TP.F_PRODUCT <>'''' AND (TP.F_TEXT_CODE LIKE ''' + @SITE + ''')'
PRINT @statement
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @statement 
END
```